# devise forgot password setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am really new to rails and have been trying to work on building an application.  I recently have installed devise and omniauth for facebook with great success after some time.  When I was reading into devise, I noticed that Devise has a "forgot password" module built into it.

I have scoured the internet and for the life of me haven't figured out how to set it up.  Is there any guide?I have been working for hours, but I haven't really had any results.    How do I set this up?  I am using rails 4.0 and the newest version of devise.

Thanks,

**Routes**

```
Omrails::Application.routes.draw do
resources :boards

resources :pins

get 'about' => "pages#about"

root :to => 'pins#index'
resources :tests, :birthdays
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks"  }
end
```

**Devise Migration:**

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
create_table(:users) do |t|
  ## Database authenticatable
  t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
  t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

  ## Recoverable
  t.string   :reset_password_token
  t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

  ## Rememberable
  t.datetime :remember_created_at

  ## Trackable
  t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0, :null => false
  t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
  t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
  t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
  t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

  ## Confirmable
  # t.string   :confirmation_token
  # t.datetime :confirmed_at
  # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

  ## Lockable
  # t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0, :null => false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
  # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
  # t.datetime :locked_at


  t.timestamps
end

add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
# add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
# add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
end
end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 

 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
 # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 devise :database_authenticatable, 
     :registerable, 
     :rememberable, 
     :trackable, 
     :recoverable,
     :validatable, 
     :omniauthable, 
     :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]


 # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
 attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :name,    :birthday, :sex, :address, :mobile, :provider, :uid

 has_many :pins, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :boards, :dependent => :destroy
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
unless user
  user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                       provider:auth.provider,
                       uid:auth.uid,
                       email:auth.info.email,
                       password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20])
end
user
end
end
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  But when I do that I get an error "undefined method `new_password_path' for #<#<Class:0x48341b8>:0x483a308>"  is that all I have to do?

Comment: Just moved my comment to ans, just in case someone else stumbles upon the same problem

Comment: can you run rake routes to see if you see the new_password route?  You'll need to restart you app to see the changes in effect

Comment: I see New_user_password but not new_password_path.  In routes.rb I have "devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }"

Comment: that's actually what you need, can you restart your server and try it again?

Comment: Your right, the error is gone now, but I still don't see any link to "forgot password" or anything to that effect.  What do I do from there.  Everything looks exactly the same since I started without :recoverable.

Comment: alright, i'm gonna need to see some code now.  can you post your routes, devise migration and the devise model?

Comment: I reset the database and that seemed to fix the problem!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Devise consists of 10 modules and the one you're looking for is recoverable. In your devise model, you need to add `:recoverable` attribute for devise.